# Setting Artifactory multi-value properties from Gradle

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am using Gradle to zip up some Artifacts and publish them to Artifactory. Another Gradle task is creating some property values that will need to be appended to the artifact. This list of values to be assigned to a single property appears in the Artifactory UI as a single value containing commas. I would rather each individual value be assigned as a member of the 'multi-value property'. This multi-value effect can be achieved in the UI by separating the values with a ; . Trying this in the join in Gradle causes Artifactory to interpret as a new property altogether instead of a new value.  Am I missing some syntax sugar here? or does this feature really only work via ui?

If relevant, Artifactory version is 5.6.3. Gradle is 4.4.1.

Stripped down build.gradle:

```
artifactory {
contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
publish {
    repository {
        repoKey = 'maven~~~'
        username = Joe
        password = Dirt
        maven = true
        defaults {
            publications('mavenJava')
            properties = ['qa.level': 'build', 'p.Vals': getPVals.pvals]
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishBuildInfo = true
            publishPom = true
            publishIvy = false
        }
    }
}
resolve {~~~
}
}
```

And stripped down value-creator task:

```
task getPVals {
  def pValList = ['val1','val2','val3']
  getPVals.ext.pvals = pValList.join(',')
}
```

Comment: what is the error message? From what you show, you want to put the `getPVals.pvals` into `artifactory.publish.repository.defaults.properties`, right?

Comment: No error messsage, just undesired behavior. The effect of the current code is that uploaded artifacts all get a property named 'p.vals' with a value of 'val1,val2,val3'. If a user searches for an artifact with a property value of 'val2' using the Artifactory UI, the search will fail. I realize searching for '(asterisk)val2(asterisk)' would work. But what I want is a 'multi-value property', not a single value with commas.